# split index overflow shell script

Tags: linux, shell, split

I have a large file of 20,000 lines called big file and would like to split it into smaller files of 5 lines each. I am using the command

```
split --lines=5 bigfile - split_
```

This gives smaller files `split_aa`, `split_ab` etc. but soon runs out of 2 letter combinations. Can you tell me how I can split into files of the form `split_aaa`, `split_aab` etc. so that the output files don't run out of indices.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `split --help`?

Comment: Thanks, split -a 3 is the fix.

Comment: You really shouldn't have needed to ask this on SO. The first steps for a problem where you need to change the behaviour of an unfamiliar command should be to get a usage message (`unfamiliar -:` usually provides some sort of usage message because `:` isn't an option on almost any command), or help (`unfamiliar --help` for commands influenced by GNU coding standards) or `man unfamiliar` (or `info unfamiliar`). Or a quick web search for the documentation will normally find the answer. Only if you've tried all those, or you need something from one of those sources explained, do you ask on SO.

Comment: JL ER, Ss, might have downgraded the OP. i chose to.

Answer (score 3):

From the [split(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) man page:

> -a, --suffix-length=N
>
> use suffixes of length N (default 2)